# How to draw text onto an image in Android

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, draw, android-shape

I have looked through countless ways of doing this but still haven't achieved the desired result; what I am trying to achieve is:

- Draw a rectangle that is the full width of the screen and about 1/3 of the screen height where the rectangle has 50% visibility / alpha (so the image can be seen slightly underneath the rectangle) and the rectangle would be placed at the very bottom of the screen
- Place a multi-line String within the rectangle where the text is centralised to the middle of the rectangle

Above is the basic concept that I am looking to achieve but also, if possible, I would like to generate a map that would be a small square and positioned on the left, within the rectangle - how to add this to a bitmap / canvas would also be really useful.

My current implementation (which doesn't have the correct shape or text size) can be seen below:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(picture, 0, picture.length);
Bitmap newBitmap = ImageUtils.drawMultilineTextToBitmapV2(MainActivity.this, bitmap, imageText);
```

...

```
public static Bitmap drawMultilineTextToBitmapV2(Context context, Bitmap bitmap, String text) {

    Bitmap.Config bitmapConfig = bitmap.getConfig();

    if (bitmapConfig == null) {
        bitmapConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    }

    Bitmap alteredBitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmapConfig, true);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(alteredBitmap);

    // Add image to canvas
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);

    // Add background for text
    Paint p2 = new Paint();
    p2.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    p2.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    p2.setAlpha(0x80);

   // int padding = 50;
    int padding = 1000;
    Rect rect = new Rect(
            canvas.getWidth() - padding, // Left
            canvas.getHeight() - padding, // Top
            padding, // Bottom
            canvas.getWidth() + padding // Right
    );
    canvas.drawRect(rect, p2);

    // Add text
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setTextSize(250);
    canvas.drawText(text, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), paint);

    canvas.save();
    return alteredBitmap;
}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

---

**UPDATE:**

```
String saveFilePath = FileUtils.saveImageToInternalStorage(newBitmap, fileDirectory, fileName, dateObject);
```

...

The bitmap / canvas gets saved to a file so it can then be accessed again by the user.

```
public static String saveImageToInternalStorage(Bitmap finalBitmap, File fileDirectory, String fileName, Date date) {

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm", Locale.UK);
    String now = simpleDateFormat.format(date);

    fileDirectory = new File(fileDirectory + DCA_FILE_PATH);
    fileDirectory.mkdirs();

    if (fileName.isEmpty()) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("000000");
        int i = 1;
        String startingNumber = df.format(i);
        fileName = now + "-" + startingNumber + ".jpg";
    } else {
        fileName = now + "-" + fileName + ".jpg";
    }

    File file = new File(fileDirectory, fileName);
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "Saving Internal File to: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    return file.getAbsolutePath();

}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Process of application:

- Take photo in-app using camera view
- Photo is returned as a byte and converted to Bitmap
- Bitmap is converted to a canvas where the text and rectangle needs to be created and then converted back to a Bitmap
- Bitmap is then saved as a file
- User clicks on file to view photo which would contain the text / rectangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved by doing:

```
public static Bitmap viewToBitmap(Activity activity, Bitmap bitmap, String mapURL, String latLong, String dateTime) {

    try {

        AsyncTask asyncTask = new BackgroundUtils.setImageFromUrl().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, mapURL);
        Bitmap googleBitmap = (Bitmap) asyncTask.get();

        Bitmap.Config bitmapConfig = bitmap.getConfig();

        if (bitmapConfig == null) {
            bitmapConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        }

        Bitmap bmp = bitmap.copy(bitmapConfig, true);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) activity.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screenshot_content, root, false);
        ImageView cameraView = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.cameraView);
        ImageView mapView = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        TextView latLongView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.latLongView);
        TextView dateTimeView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.dateTimeView);

        cameraView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        mapView.setImageBitmap(googleBitmap);
        latLongView.setText(latLong);
        dateTimeView.setText(dateTime);

        layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        layout.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(canvas.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(canvas.getHeight(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
        layout.layout(0, 0, layout.getMeasuredWidth(), layout.getMeasuredHeight());
        layout.draw(canvas);

        return bmp;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using relative layout (it is possible by frame also),you can set the image view in the layout and add the square or any other layout above it with any position you want.Something like this code in your xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/bg_gv_item"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_gv_medical_guide_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_category_title"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_category_title_rounded_rectangle"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

with the drawable bg for your textview, you can control it as you like (1/3) of the screen or whatever you want. Hope this can help you a little bit.

Comment: The reason for it being a bitmap / canvas is because it needs to be saved as a .jpg file - I have updated the original question to show this code too. Are you able to suggest a way of achieving the desired result and then saving the image thereafter?

Comment: @TobyClench you can desgin your layout as you like, then you can take a screen shot from it and save it as bitmap ;)

Comment: Can't really do that as the user takes a photo in-app and then in the background the file is being created (with the text and rectangle) whilst the user is returned back to the camera view again. Original question has been updated to outline the process of what the application does - so can you suggest a way to achieve this by using the Bitmap (or another method), applying the rectangle and text & then saving as a file?

Comment: yes it is the same concept, you can create the layout and make it invisible, so when user take a photo you can put the photo in the my suggested layout (which is now invisible) and take the screen shot by passing the layout id to the screenshot method (it will create a bitmap image for your invisible layout) then display the result wherever you want.

Comment: That sounds like it would work - can you please provide an answer of how to achieve this (the layout being invisible with the rectangle and text at the bottom with 50% opacity / alpha on the rectangle) and then how to take the screenshot of the invisible view and create the bitmap? As then, if it works, I will mark it as the accepted answer - thanks